# Group by 2 columns and create an orderID based on this grouping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would to create a distinct order ID based upon 2 columns: quarter and location.

**Data**

```
location    type    quarter 
ny          aa      1   
ny          aa      1   
ny          bb      1   
ny          aa      2   
ny          aa      2   
ny          bb      2   
ca          cc      3   
ca          aa      3
```

**Desired**

```
location    type    quarter Id
ny          aa      1       aa01
ny          aa      1       aa02
ny          bb      1       bb01
ny          aa      2       aa01
ny          aa      2       aa02
ny          bb      2       bb01
ca          cc      3       cc01
ca          aa      3       aa01
```

Order Id takes the type and adds a numerical value to the end of it based upon how many of that type is in the quarter and location.

**Doing**

I am going about this by:

```
df['type']     = df.groupby('type').ngroup()
df['location'] = df.groupby('location').ngroup()
```

This will group the columns, however this is separate solution, I would like all the original columns to be maintained and kept in my dataframe.

Any suggestion is appreciated. I am still researching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your expected ouput is necesary grouping by 3 columns with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), add `1` because starting counter by `0`, convert to strings and add `0` for minimal 2 digits by [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) and add to `type` column:

```
s = df.groupby(['location','type','quarter']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df['Id'] = df['type'] + s
print (df)
  location type  quarter    Id
0       ny   aa        1  aa01
1       ny   aa        1  aa02
2       ny   bb        1  bb01
3       ny   aa        2  aa01
4       ny   aa        2  aa02
5       ny   bb        2  bb01
6       ca   cc        3  cc01
7       ca   aa        3  aa01
```