# Groupby two columns and add leading zeros in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, `df`, where I would like to group by two columns and add leading zeros:

**Data**

```
id  date    type
aa  q1 21   hi
aa  q1 21   hi
aa  q2 22   hey
aa  q2 22   hi
aa  q2 22   hi
bb  q1 21   hi
bb  q1 21   hey
```

**Desired**

```
Ultimately grouping by 'id' and 'date'

id  date    type    count
aa  q1 21   hi      hi01
aa  q1 21   hi      hi02
aa  q2 22   hey     hey01
aa  q2 22   hi      hi01
aa  q2 22   hi      hi02
bb  q1 21   hi      hi01
bb  q1 21   hey     hey01
```

**Doing**

```
# Adding zeros, researching how to incorporate the groupby
df1 = df['count'].str.extract(r'(\D+)(\d+)$')
df['count'] = df[0].str.upper() + df[1].str.zfill(2)
```

Comment: `df["type"].add(df.groupby(["id", "date"]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2))`

Comment: @user3483203 I don't think the question you marked is a duplicate of this. Also, that snippet you posted doesn't produce the OP's expected output. Will you please consider reopening? I have an answer.

Comment: If you notice, the count for `hi` in group `aa` resets after `hey`. Your code does not do that.

Comment: If that's the case, just add `type` into the grouping and it matches.

Comment: ah I see so it should be df["type"].add(df.groupby(["id", "type", "date"]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2))   @user17242583

Comment: @user17242583 can you explain how its not a duplicate? It's a groupby + cumcount.  The only thing I missed in my initial comment was which columns to group on.

Comment: Well, it's similar, because it does a cumcount, but it doesn't talk about grouping, whereas this question has specific (and somewhat complex) grouping requirements. I have a perfect answer anyway... @user3483203

Comment: It seems this is almost an exact duplicate of OP's previous question: [Group by 2 columns and create an orderID based on this grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67631910/15497888) _including_ the `str.zfill` and concatenation (the only difference is the column names). (I've updated duplicate list)